# Power of stochastic kernel (transposition probability function)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-chains

I am reading the following book:

`Markov Chains and Invariant Probabilities, by Herndadez-Lerma and Lasserre` (p.23)

1. Given measure space $(X,\mathcal{B})$

For each $x\in X$ and $B\in \mathcal{B}$, let $$P(x,B)=\mathcal{P}(\xi_{n+1}\in B \mid \xi_n = x).$$ This defines a stochastic kernel on $X$, which means

1. $P(x,\cdot)$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{B}$ for each fixed $x\in X$.
2. $P(\cdot,B)$ is a measurable function on $X$ for each fixed $B\in \mathcal{B}$.

The $n-$step stochastic kernel $P^n(x,B)$ can be defined recursively by 
$$P^n(x,B) = \int_XP(x,dy)P^{n-1}(y,B) = \int_XP^{n-1}(x,dy)P(y,B)$$

with $P^0(x,\cdot) = \delta_x(\cdot)$.

Based on this definition,

$$P^1(x,B) = \int_X P^0(x,dy)P(y,B) = \int_x P(y,B)\delta_x(dy) = P(x,B).$$

$$P^2(x,B) = \int_X P^1(x,dy)P(y,B) = \int_X P(y,B) \int_X P(y,dy)\delta_x(dy)$$

and then we have

$$P^2(x,B) =  = \int_X P(y,B)  P(y,dy)\delta_x(dy) = P(x,B) \int_X   P(y,dy)\delta_x(dy)$$

> I have no idea how to say $\int_X   P(y,dy)\delta_x(dy) =P(x,B) $.
>
> Moreover, can anyone let me know the meaning of such definition of $P^n(x,B)$ from the perspective of Markov Chain (this definition seems difficult to understand for me)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int f(y) d\delta_x(y)=f(x)$ for any non-negative measurable function $f$.

$P^{n}(x,B)$ is the probability of starting at $x$ at time $0$ and landing inside $B$ in $n$ steps. 
You have made a mistake with $P^{2}(x,B)$. You should write $P^{2}(x,B)=\int_X  P^{1}(y,B) P^{1}(x,dy)$. It is not possible to pull out $P(x,B)$ from this.

Comment: Your first answer is what I used in deriving $P(x,B)$. Would you mind to give me more detailed comment about my derivation of $P^2(x,B)$?

Comment: Why can't I put out $P(x,B)$? The reason I do this is because $x$ and $B$ are not function of $y$. Is it not true?

Comment: In your formula for $P^{2}$ there should be a third variable $z$. You cannot have $dy$ appearing twice in that formula. You will not have $P(x,B)$ in that formula.